# How to determine whether a list of figures is empty, then not show it at all?

Tags: table-of-contents, conditionals

I want to check whether the document has any figures so as to decide whether or not to have a list of figures. Is this possible? Feasible without doing something like parsing the lof file?

Note that checking whether the lof file is empty is not a good enough solution for me, as some code may be writing things other than table lines into it (e.g. `babel`).

Comment: What about checking whether the `*.lof` (and `*.lot`) file exists at all?

Comment: @ThorstenDonig: `\listoffigures` calls `\@starttoc{lof}` which creates/writes to `\jobname.lof`. So `\jobname.lof` only exists based the call `\listoffigures`. Checking for its existence is therefore "too late".

Comment: So, [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/297600/5640) is a related question from today:

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The idea behind this attempt is to use standard LaTeX references in order to detect whether a `figure` was used in the document. Here are the steps involved (with some modifications by @egreg):

1. Conjure up a label name that you won't use in your document, ever. Something like `fig:was:used:in:doc`.
2. Patch the `figure` environment to define an empty command (say) `\there@is@a@figure` at the end of *every* figure. This is possible using the [`etoolbox` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) which provides `\AtEndEnvironment`. More specifically, the command

   ```
   \AtEndEnvironment{figure}{\gdef\there@is@a@figure{}}
   ```

   will be perpetually redefined until the last `figure` in the document.
3. At the end of the document, we check whether `\there@is@a@figure` exists (is defined), and define a label `\label{fig:was:used:in:doc}`. It doesn't really matter what this label contains (it could be the last used figure, section, table, or whatever):

   ```
   \AtEndDocument{\ifdefined\there@is@a@figure\label{fig:was:used:in:doc}\fi}
   ```
4. Write your own "conditional LoF" command using

   ```
   \newcommand{\conditionalLoF}{\@ifundefined{r@fig:was:used:in:doc}{}{\listoffigures}}%
   ```

   The command `\conditionalLoF` checks whether the macro `\r@fig:was:used:in:doc` is defined or not. This is the standard LaTeX referencing mechanism at work, since each label `<lab>` has an associated macro `\r@<lab>` defined. `\@ifundefined{<cs>}{<undef code>}{<def code>}` allows execution of `<undef code>` if `<cs>` is undefined, otherwise execute `<def code>`.
5. Use `\conditionalLoF` instead of `\listoffigures`.
6. Compile your document at least 3 times.

The main idea behind (1) is to have the label `fig:was:used:in:doc` only exist when using a `figure`, and not having to worry about what it is called. (2) provides the hook to the `figure` environment and allows a global (re)definition of `\there@is@a@figure`. (3) delays the definition of the `fig:was:used:in:doc` label until the end of the document in order to avoid causing "Multiply defined label" warnings. (4) and (5) provides a clean interface to the conditional LoF. (6) may be the only drawback. However, this comes standard with label referencing, requiring at least two compiles to work in general.

Here's a minimal working example (MWE). It uses [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) (with the `demo` package option) and [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) merely for show and is therefore actually not necessary. Compiling this MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\makeatletter
\AtEndEnvironment{figure}{\gdef\there@is@a@figure{}} 
\AtEndDocument{\ifdefined\there@is@a@figure\label{fig:was:used:in:doc}\fi} 
\newcommand{\conditionalLoF}{\@ifundefined{r@fig:was:used:in:doc}{}{\listoffigures}}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\conditionalLoF% Conditionally insert List of Figures
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1]
%\begin{figure}
%  \centering\includegraphics{figure}
%  \caption{This is a caption}
%\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

as-is produces

[image]

Uncommenting the `figure` environment and compiling a couple of times produces

[image]

Comment: This will cause spurious "Multiply defined label" messages.

Comment: I've added code that won't show the problem, you can integrate it into your answer (the idea is just the same).

Comment: Absolutely correct. Is there a way to append (say) a counter to the label `fig:was:used:in:doc` and then only check for (say) `\r@fig:was:used:in:doc:1`?

Comment: You'll have seen my addition, by now. :)

Comment: Thanks - that's awesome and a good patch to avoid the warnings!

Comment: @egreg: Thanks again; I weaved your improvement into my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try in my document, but - there are a few buts: 1. This seems only to work for figures, not for a Table of Contents or other such tables. 2. Someone might write a "myfigure" environment which adds to the list of figures using whatever sub-command used by the figure environment, and I will be none the wiser. 3. I would rather, if possible, use the mechanism the figure environment uses to add entries to the list, rather than create a new and idiosyncratic one.

Comment: Why isn't this behaviour the default?

Answer (score 8):

A different approach is using the `totalcount` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum

\usepackage[figure]{totalcount}

\begin{document}

% Conditionally insert List of Figures
\iftotalfigures
  \listoffigures
\fi

\section{First section}
\lipsum[1]

%\begin{figure}
%  \centering\includegraphics{figure}
%  \caption{This is a caption}
%\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's much nicer, I'll need to try it out...

Comment: Next time I have an LoF, that is.

Comment: This question is quite old, but compared to the convoluted answers in the other ones, this package does the job wonderfully.

Comment: much nicer indeed

Comment: Why isn't this behaviour the default?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a combination of `totcount` and `assoccnt` (it's combined in `xassoccnt` now, at least some features of  `totcount`)

`xassoccnt` defines counters that step with a master counter, say `figure` but are not reset if `figure` is set to zero, i.e. the `totalfigures` counter holds the total number of figures (unless manipulated directly).

Using the `\NewTotalDocumentFeature`, the value of a total counter is written to the `.aux` file at the end of the compilation run and read in in the next run, i.e. the number of figures is known at the start of the document.

Werner used the `refcount` approach together with `assoccnt` (which is the predecessor of `xassoccnt`, which is much more developed than `assoccnt` (I know about the states -- I am the author of `(x)assoccnt` ;-))

I redefined the `\listof...` commands slightly.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xassoccnt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\NewTotalDocumentCounter{totalfigures}
\NewTotalDocumentCounter{totaltables}

\DeclareAssociatedCounters{figure}{totalfigures}
\DeclareAssociatedCounters{table}{totaltables}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\TotalValue}[1]{%  A small bug fix
  \value{xassoccnt@total@#1}%
}


\let\@@latex@@listoffigures\listoffigures
\let\@@latex@@listoftables\listoftables

\renewcommand{\listoffigures}{%
  \ifnum\TotalValue{totalfigures} > 0 
  \@@latex@@listoffigures%
  \fi
}


\renewcommand{\listoftables}{%
  \ifnum\TotalValue{totaltables} > 0 
  \@@latex@@listoftables%
  \fi
}


\makeatother





\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\clearpage


\listoftables

\listoffigures


A figure:

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{A picture}
\label{fig:label}
\end{figure}

A table:

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
%\caption{A table}
\label{tab:label}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lX}
test & test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you explain what these two packages are about, and how your solution compares to @AxeSommerfeldt's [solution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/297657/5640)?

Comment: By the way, is there some special reason this question is getting attention, over 4 years after I accepted a solution?

Comment: @einpoklum: There was a similar question today ;-)

Comment: A dupe? If not, link it please...

Comment: @einpoklum: Not a real dupe, in my point of view.

Answer (score 0):

One could use the [`assoccnt` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/assoccnt) where you can associate a counter with some other *master* counter, stepping it in tandem. At the end of the document, you write out a `\label` that would capture the existing total count of the associated counter. Then, using [`refcount`](http://ctan.org/pkg/refcount)'s expandable `\getrefnumber`, a conditional LoF (or other Table of Contents structure) could be printed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum,assoccnt,refcount}
\newcounter{totfigure}% This will capture the total number of figures
\DeclareAssociatedCounters{figure}{totfigure}% Step totfigure with every figure
\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument{%
  \edef\@currentlabel{\arabic{totfigure}}% Update current \label value
  \label{tot:figs:used:in:doc}}% Mark \label
\newcommand{\conditionalLoF}{%
  \ifnum\getrefnumber{tot:figs:used:in:doc}>0 % Check whether 'totfigure' > 0
    \listoffigures\fi}% If so, print \listoffigures
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\conditionalLoF% Conditionally insert List of Figures
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1]
%\begin{figure}
  %\centering\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image}
  %\caption{This is a caption}
%\end{figure}
\end{document}
```