# automatic generation of list of tables in book/report writing

Tags: table-of-contents

I am writing a thesis using document class -book. The list of table is not generated automatically like the list of figure and table of contents. Please help me out.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: None of those elements are automatically generated by the `book` class without adding the appropriate `\tableofcontents`, `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables`.  Have you done this?  Are each of your tables inside `\begin{table}` ... `\end{table}` environments?

Comment: The first thing I would check is that `\jobname.lot` is being generated correctly- that's where the information for `\listoftables` is stored.

Comment: Perhaps this discussion at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33193/how-to-determine-whether-a-list-of-figures-is-empty might be of interest in creating `\listoffigures` (or `\listoftables`) only when `figure` (or `table`) was used.

Answer (score 12):

The list of tables is generated by the command `\listoftables`; but like `\listoffigures` it's not really the list of tables: it lists all the `\caption` commands appearing inside `table` environments; so if you say

```
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{...}
...
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

nothing will appear in the list of tables.

One of the most diffuse prejudices is that a command `\includegraphics` can only appear inside a `figure` environments and often users confuse `table` with `tabular`.

`\listoftables` will *not* list `tabular` environments, but only those `table` environments that contain at least one `\caption` command (which might contain a `tabular`, but are not required to).

Answer (score 4):

Do check two things: First, has the `\listoftables` command (should be located in the vicinity of the `\listoffigures` command) either been deleted or commented out (possibly by accident)? Second, do you maybe have only unnumbered table environments? If so, they won't show up in the List-of-Tables section by default.

Answer (score 1):

If the other answers do not fix the problem (like in my case), be sure to **not** have empty square brackets following your `\caption` command like in this faulty example:

```
\caption[]{Description}
```

This goes for tables as well as for figures.

Also be sure to compile 2-3 times to allow for all references to be gathered iteratively.

Comment: How does this influence the automatic generation of the List of Figures/Tables? It just sends an empty caption to those structures, but there will still be an entry in the LoF/LoT.

Comment: For my setup only the heading showed up, no entry, not even an empty one with page number. Using Texmaker 4.2, LaTeX2e <2016/03/31>, MiKTeX 2.9.