# Conditional list of listings - lstlistoflistings only if listings are present

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, listings

As shown in [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33193/how-to-determine-whether-a-list-of-figures-is-empty-then-not-show-it-at-all) and [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234398/list-of-figures-and-tables-when-there-are-no-figures-or-tables) it is possible to conditionally create lists of figures and tables only if these items are used in a document.

I would like to extends this to listings. Everything works fine as long as you use the `lstlisting` environment at least once in the document. Normally, I include code with `\lstinputlisting`. Therefore, the `lstlisting` environment is not used. Thus, the `\AtEndEnvironmet`is never called and the command `\conditionalLoL` is never set to true.

Is there a way modify the definition of `\conditionalLoL` to include `\lstinputlisting` ?

---

Code so far:

```
\documentclass[listof=totoc]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tabularx}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33193/how-to-determine-whether-a-list-of-figures-is-empty-then-not-show-it-at-all
\makeatletter
  % Figure
  \AtEndEnvironment{figure}{\gdef\there@is@a@figure{}}%
  \AtEndDocument{\ifdefined\there@is@a@figure\label{fig:was:used:in:doc}\fi}%
  \newcommand{\conditionalLoF}{\@ifundefined{r@fig:was:used:in:doc}{}{\listoffigures}}%
  % Table
  \AtEndEnvironment{table}{\gdef\there@is@a@table{}}%
  \AtEndDocument{\ifdefined\there@is@a@table\label{tab:was:used:in:doc}\fi}%
  \newcommand{\conditionalLoT}{\@ifundefined{r@tab:was:used:in:doc}{}{\listoftables}}%
  % Listing
  \AtEndEnvironment{lstlisting}{\gdef\there@is@a@listing{}}%
  \AtEndDocument{\ifdefined\there@is@a@listing\label{lst:was:used:in:doc}\fi}%
  \newcommand{\conditionalLoL}{\@ifundefined{r@lst:was:used:in:doc}{}{\lstlistoflistings}}%
  % 
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents*}{command.txt}
Line 1
Line 2
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\clearpage
\tableofcontents

\conditionalLoF
\let\LaTeXStandardClearpage\clearpage
\let\clearpage\relax
\conditionalLoT
\conditionalLoL
\let\clearpage\LaTeXStandardClearpage % Return to the old definition

\vspace{1cm}

A figure:

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{A picture}
\label{fig:label}
\end{figure}

A table:

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{A table}
\label{tab:label}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lX}
test & test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

A listing environment:

% \begin{lstlisting}[label=lst:label1,caption=A listing]
% command
% command
% \end{lstlisting}

A lstinputlisting:

\lstinputlisting[label=lst:label2,caption=Another listing]{command.txt}

\end{document}
```

---

Result with lstlisting environment:

[image: with lstlisting]

---

Result only with listinputlisting:

[image]

### Update

Using @Axel Sommerfeldt's answer I still got an empty list of tables for my original document. I found out that this is caused by a `longtabu` environment in my documentclass. Following is the MWE with `longtabu` causing an empty list of tables:

```
\documentclass[listof=totoc]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[figure,table,lstlisting]{totalcount}

\newcommand\conditionalLoF{%
  \iftotalfigures\listoffigures\fi}
\newcommand\conditionalLoT{%
  \iftotaltables\listoftables\fi}
\newcommand\conditionalLoL{%
  \iftotallstlistings\lstlistoflistings\fi}

\begin{filecontents*}{command.txt}
Line 1
Line 2
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\clearpage
\tableofcontents

\conditionalLoF
\let\LaTeXStandardClearpage\clearpage
\let\clearpage\relax
\conditionalLoT
\conditionalLoL
\let\clearpage\LaTeXStandardClearpage % Return to the old definition

\vspace{1cm}

\newpage

\chapter{Tests}

\section{Figures}

A figure:

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{A picture}
\label{fig:label}
\end{figure}

A non-floating picture:

\includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth]{example-image-a}

\section{Tables}

% A table:
% 
% \begin{table}[htbp]
% \centering
% \caption{A table}
% \label{tab:label}
% \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lX}
% test & test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
% \end{tabularx}
% \end{table}
% 
% A non-floating table:
% 
% \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lX}
% test & test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
% \end{tabularx}

A non-floating longtabu

\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {lX}
test & test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
\end{longtabu}

\section{Listings}

A listing environment:

\begin{lstlisting}[label=lst:label1,caption=A listing environment]
command
command
\end{lstlisting}

A lstinputlisting:

\lstinputlisting[label=lst:label2,caption=A lstinputlisting]{command.txt}

\end{document}
```

I had a quick look at the [`tabu`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabu?lang=de) package documentation. But I am not sure why the counter for tables is added to for an non-floating `longtabu` in the [`totalcount`](http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/caption/totalcount.pdf) package.

Any ideas?

Comment: Off-topic: `\label` must be placed **after** `\caption`, not before!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A solution using the `totalcount` package:

```
\usepackage[figure,table,lstlisting]{totalcount}

\newcommand\conditionalLoF{%
  \iftotalfigures\listoffigures\fi}
\newcommand\conditionalLoT{%
  \iftotaltables\listoftables\fi}
\newcommand\conditionalLoL{%
  \iftotallstlistings\lstlistoflistings\fi}
```

The complete example document:

```
\documentclass[listof=totoc]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[figure,table,lstlisting]{totalcount}

\newcommand\conditionalLoF{%
  \iftotalfigures\listoffigures\fi}
\newcommand\conditionalLoT{%
  \iftotaltables\listoftables\fi}
\newcommand\conditionalLoL{%
  \iftotallstlistings\lstlistoflistings\fi}

\begin{filecontents*}{command.txt}
Line 1
Line 2
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\clearpage
\tableofcontents

\conditionalLoF
\let\LaTeXStandardClearpage\clearpage
\let\clearpage\relax
\conditionalLoT
\conditionalLoL
\let\clearpage\LaTeXStandardClearpage % Return to the old definition

\vspace{1cm}

A figure:

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{A picture}
\label{fig:label}
\end{figure}

A table:

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{A table}
\label{tab:label}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lX}
test & test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

A listing environment:

% \begin{lstlisting}[label=lst:label1,caption=A listing]
% command
% command
% \end{lstlisting}

A lstinputlisting:

\lstinputlisting[label=lst:label2,caption=Another listing]{command.txt}

\end{document}
```

Opposite to the solutions given by the other answers this solution is actually based on the counter usage (instead of the environment usage). So for example this solution works when using `\captionof`, too, where the other ones fail:

```
\documentclass[listof=totoc]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[figure,table]{totalcount}

\newcommand\conditionalLoF{%
  \iftotalfigures\listoffigures\fi}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\conditionalLoF

\vspace{1cm}

A figure:

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\captionof{figure}{A picture}
\label{fig:label}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

**Some additional notes:**

The main problem with your question is that there is no perfect solution.

If you add flags to the environments (like the solution from Werner does) you will miss entries to the list of figures/tables. You add a flag to `table`, `longtable`, and `longtabu`, you will miss `threeparttable` and `wraptable` and many others. If you add flags to them, too, you will miss `\captionof{table}` which is totally independent of the environment used. (And you will miss other entries as well.) And a `table` without `\caption` will lead to a wrong outcome, too.

If you use the counter approach (like my solution using `totalcount`) you have problems with code which increments the counter but does not place an entry within the List of Tables, e.g. `longtable` or `longtabu` without `\caption`. You can correct this by decrementing the counter after usage of these environments. But what about a table with `\caption[]{...}`? This does add a caption, does increment the table counter, but does not produce an entry in the List of Tables either.

A third approach would be patching `\caption`. But not every environment incrementing the figure or table counter does use `\caption`, e.g. the `hvfigure` environment offered by the `hvfloat` package. And what `\caption` to patch? There are many different `\caption` commands, for example a total different code will be used for `table` and `longtable`. My `caption` package tries to patch many flavors of `\caption` (the one of the LaTeX kernel and of 17 additional packages), but not all of them. So if I would offer a solution within my `caption` package it would not work with all environments, e.g. environments defined by the `algorithm2e` package since the `caption` package is not adapted to this package. (And I don't know `longtabu`, must take a closer look on the next week-end. And I will offer an alternate solution using my `caption` package on the next week-end, too.)

So unfortunately you have to choose a solution which fits your needs best. There is no perfect one since any package/environment/command is free to increment the counters, and free to add something to the List of Figures/Tables using its very own code.

**Addendum 2016-03-13**
As promised a different solution which patches `\addcontentsline` to handle conditional lists:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{listings,longtable,tabu}

\begin{filecontents*}{command.txt}
Line 1
Line 2
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{iflistof.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/12/01]
\ProvidesPackage{iflistof}[2016/03/12 v0.1 Offers conditional "List of" (AS)]
\providecommand*\iflistof[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{iflistof@#1}\@secondoftwo\@firstoftwo}
\let\ORI@addcontentsline\addcontentsline
\renewcommand*\addcontentsline[2]{%
  \caption@iflistof{iflistof@#2}%
  \ORI@addcontentsline{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand*\caption@iflistof[1]{%
% \@nameuse{#1}{%
    \global\@namedef{#1}{\@secondoftwo}%
    \if@filesw
      \immediate\write\@mainaux{%
        \string\global\string\@namedef{#1}{\string\@firstoftwo}}%
    \fi}%{}}
\endinput
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{iflistof}

\begin{document}
\iflistof{figure}{\listoffigures}{}
\iflistof{table}{\listoftables}{}
\iflistof{lstlisting}{\lstlistoflistings}{}
\clearpage

%\begin{table}
%  \caption{A table}
%\end{table}

\begin{longtable}{ll}
\caption{A longtable}\\
\end{longtable}

\begin{longtabu}{ll}
\caption{A longtable}\\
\end{longtabu}

% \begin{lstlisting}[label=lst:label1,caption=A listing]
% command
% command
% \end{lstlisting}

\lstinputlisting[label=lst:label2,caption=Another listing]{command.txt}

\end{document}
```

This seems to be the best approach, but before praising it please play around with it a little bit and report. If it proves well I could add the `iflistof` package to my "caption package bundle".

See also: https://sourceforge.net/p/latex-caption/tickets/37/

Comment: Thanks. That works great for the MWE and adds flexibility. Unfortunately an empty list of tables is shown in case a non-floating `longtabu` is used. Please see my updated question.

Comment: `longtabu` (like `longtable`) always increases the table counter. If you don't have a caption you could use `\addtocounter{table}{-1}` afterwards to decrease the counter, and this way no LoT will be typeset since the `totalcount` package is only looking at the counter when being reset (e.g. by `\chapter') and at the end of the document. And if you typeset a `longtabu` and decrease the counter afterwards, it will be 0 at the end of the document (as long as you don't have other tables), and therefore `\iftotaltables` will be false.

Comment: Thanks for that information. Since I would like to start clean after the preamble, is there something like `\setcounter{table}{0}` that I can call before `\begin{document}` ?

Comment: Yes, exactly that works. Could you tell me why longtable and longtable increase the table counter?

Comment: I added some additional notes at the end of my solution (since this would be too long for getting a comment).

Comment: Regarding `longtable`: Usually `\caption` increments the counter. But a `longtable` can have many captions, for example one for every page typesetting a table spanning two pages results in two captions. But both captions must have the same counter value (since it's the same table), so the author of the `longtable` designed it this way: Every `longtable` increments the table counter at `\begin{longtable}{...}` (and *not* at `\caption`). This is confusing to users of LaTeX since there is no standard behavior anymore,`table` behaves different than `longtable` here. (Same problem with `longtabu`.)

Comment: I just added a third approach to my answer which patches `\addcontentsline` to reach its goal.

Answer (score 3):

Try (well, my ;-)) package `xassoccnt`, which provides some of the `totcount` features and associated counters that are **not** reset if the `figure` etc. counter is set to zero, i.e. they are increased continously (unless manipulated directly) -- in conjunction with the `Total` counter feature the values are stored to the `.aux` file and are available in the second run.

A slight redefinition of `\listof....` checks for the counter value to be greater than zero and loads the relevant original `\listof...` command. If the counter is zero, then nothing is included.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xassoccnt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\NewTotalDocumentCounter{totalfigures}
\NewTotalDocumentCounter{totaltables}
\NewTotalDocumentCounter{totallistings}

\DeclareAssociatedCounters{lstlisting}{totallistings}
\DeclareAssociatedCounters{figure}{totalfigures}
\DeclareAssociatedCounters{table}{totaltables}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\TotalValue}[1]{%
  \value{xassoccnt@total@#1}%
}


\let\@@latex@@listoffigures\listoffigures
\let\@@latex@@listoftables\listoftables
\let\@@latex@@lstlistoflistings\lstlistoflistings

\renewcommand{\listoffigures}{%
  \ifnum\TotalValue{totalfigures} > 0 
  \@@latex@@listoffigures%
  \fi
}


\renewcommand{\listoftables}{%
  \ifnum\TotalValue{totaltables} > 0 
  \@@latex@@listoftables%
  \fi
}


\renewcommand{\lstlistoflistings}{%
  \ifnum\TotalValue{totallistings} > 0 
  \@@latex@@lstlistoflistings%
  \fi
}

\makeatother





\begin{filecontents*}{command.txt}
Line 1
Line 2
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\clearpage

\lstlistoflistings

\listoftables

\listoffigures


A figure:

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth]{example-image-a}
%\caption{A picture}
\label{fig:label}
\end{figure}

A table:

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{A table}
\label{tab:label}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lX}
test & test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

A listing environment:

\begin{lstlisting}[label=lst:label1,caption=A listing]
  command
  command
\end{lstlisting}

A lstinputlisting:

\lstinputlisting[label=lst:label2,caption=Another listing]{command.txt}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I use your approach I get a list of tables in my original document even if no table environment is used throughout the document.

Comment: @krtek: Have you compiled twice? I don't get a list of table if there's no table (or just comment out the `\caption` of your table

Comment: of course. I compile three times by default with PDFLaTeX. Could this be an issue with the `calc` package? Despite I did not call the package explicitely, I initially received an error by `xassoccnt`. I  modified my preamble according to `xassoccnt` documentation and not even get a warning right now.

Comment: Load `calc` before `xassoccnt`! `calc` does 'weird' setups! It's stated clearly in the `xassoccnt` documentation that `calc` must be loaded before. Either you have some strange setup, but your 'minimal' document runs without problems for me

Comment: I do. I had a look at the `lot`-file of my document. It is not empty. The thing is, I do use tabularx-tables but not inside a table environment and without label or caption. I got the following lines in my `lot`-file: `\select@language {english}` two times and afterwards seven times 
`\addvspace {10\p@ }`

Comment: @krtek: Remove all `.lot` etc. and `.aux` files, make a clean double run. My setup does not check whether `.lot` etc. is empty, just if the total... counter values are greater than zero.

Comment: I did, same result.

Comment: @krtek: Well, you seem to have a strange setup -- I can't help here then. I know that my setup work, for a minimal document, but I can't help on non-available code

Comment: @krtek: I switched to `scrreprt` and cannot reproduce your issue -- sorry, the issue must have another source

Comment: I think I found the problem. My original document builds up on `scrreprt` with the `listof=totoc` option. If I use scrreprt as documentclass with this option in my MWE the same problem occurs. It does not with `scrartcl`. New first line: `\documentclass[listof=totoc]{scrreprt}`

Comment: @krtek: Well, if you would have given this information before a lot of comments would have been unnecessary. There's not much I can do here. I don't provide support for weird settings in KOMA classes

Answer (score 1):

It should be obvious that the code relies on the existence of a `figure`, `table` and `lstlisting` *environment*. However, `\lstinputlisting` doesn't use an `lstlisting` environment (internally), and therefore it doesn't function as expected.

The code below changes `\lstinputlisting` by prepending to it the conditional component for detecting the existence of a listing:

```
\makeatletter
\let\oldlstinputlisting\lstinputlisting
\renewcommand{\lstinputlisting}{\gdef\there@is@a@listing{}\oldlstinputlisting}
\makeatother
```

Here is a complete minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{etoolbox,listings}

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33193/how-to-determine-whether-a-list-of-figures-is-empty-then-not-show-it-at-all
\makeatletter
  % Figure
  \AtEndEnvironment{figure}{\gdef\there@is@a@figure{}}%
  \AtEndDocument{\ifdefined\there@is@a@figure\label{fig:was:used:in:doc}\fi}%
  \newcommand{\conditionalLoF}{\@ifundefined{r@fig:was:used:in:doc}{}{\listoffigures}}%
  % Table
  \AtEndEnvironment{table}{\gdef\there@is@a@table{}}%
  \AtEndDocument{\ifdefined\there@is@a@table\label{tab:was:used:in:doc}\fi}%
  \newcommand{\conditionalLoT}{\@ifundefined{r@tab:was:used:in:doc}{}{\listoftables}}%
  % Listing
  \AtEndEnvironment{lstlisting}{\gdef\there@is@a@listing{}}%
  \let\oldlstinputlisting\lstinputlisting
  \renewcommand{\lstinputlisting}{\gdef\there@is@a@listing{}\oldlstinputlisting}
  \AtEndDocument{\ifdefined\there@is@a@listing\label{lst:was:used:in:doc}\fi}%
  \newcommand{\conditionalLoL}{\@ifundefined{r@lst:was:used:in:doc}{}{\lstlistoflistings}}%
  % 
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents*}{command.txt}
Line 1
Line 2
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\clearpage
\tableofcontents

\conditionalLoF
\let\LaTeXStandardClearpage\clearpage
\let\clearpage\relax
\conditionalLoT
\conditionalLoL
\let\clearpage\LaTeXStandardClearpage % Return to the old definition

\vspace{1cm}

A figure:

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{A picture}
\end{figure}

A table:

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{A table}
\end{table}

A listing environment:

% \begin{lstlisting}[label=lst:label1,caption=A listing]
% command
% command
% \end{lstlisting}

A lstinputlisting:

\lstinputlisting[label=lst:label2,caption=Another listing]{command.txt}

\end{document}
```