# Equivalent of \iftotalfigures for xequations

Tags: equations, conditionals

To print my lists only when there are references I use the following syntax:

```
% List of figures
\iftotalfigures\listoffigures\fi
% List of tables
\iftotaltables\listoftables\fi
```

Now I would like to use the same for my xequations like this:

```
% List of xequations
\iftotalxequations\listofxequations\fi
```

My declaration is like this:

```
\DeclareNewTOC[
  counterwithin=chapter,
  name=equation, 
  type=xequation, 
  nonfloat, 
]{loe}

\AtBeginDocument{
\newcaptionname{ngerman}\xequationname{Gleichung}
\newcaptionname{ngerman}\listxequationname{Gleichungsverzeichnis}
}
```

-

```
\begin{xequation-}
\begin{gather}
\begin{aligned}
a &= b\\
\label{eq:1}
\end{aligned}\\
\begin{array}{lll}
\text{mit:} &&\\
a & \text{--} & \text{Test [1]}\\
b & \text{--} & \text{Test [1]}
\end{array}
\notag
\end{gather}
\caption[Test]{Test}
\end{xequation-}
```

But `\iftotalxequations` is not defined. Is there an easy way to define it?

Comment: What is the `xequation-` environment?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I found some working examples... For [example](https://golatex.de/selbsterstelltes-verzeichnis-anzeigeformat-t13408.html)

Comment: @Passe it's helpful that you provided examples, unfortunately none of them is a full MWE (Minimal Working Example, or Minimalbeispiel in German). A MWE is complete, which means that it contains everything to recreate the issue, including `\documentclass`, `\usepackage` statements, the contents, and `\end{document}`, all put together in a single code example. Luckily, on the page you linked there is an MWE at the bottom that I could use for my answer - maybe for your next question you can try to include a code example with this convention yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained by the first answer to [Conditional list of listings - lstlistoflistings only if listings are present](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297600/conditional-list-of-listings-lstlistoflistings-only-if-listings-are-present) you can use the `totalcount` package to define `\iftotalxequations`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[listof=entryprefix]{scrartcl}
\DeclareNewTOC[%
   name=Formula,
   type=xequation,
   nonfloat,
]{loe}
\usepackage[xequation]{totalcount}
\begin{document}
\iftotalxequations\listofxequations\fi
\begin{xequation-}  
$a=b$
\caption{P-Anteil}
\end{xequation-}

\begin{xequation-}  
$E=mc^2$
\caption{Einstein}
\end{xequation-}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!